# Parse and modify multiple XML files

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree, xml.etree

I am trying to

1. read multiple XML files from a folder
2. modify them (remove the content of two tags)
3. replace the old XML file with the new one

This is the code I got so far:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import glob

#parse xml files
filenames = glob.glob("[0-9][a-z](*).xml")

for filename in filenames:

    with open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as content:

        tree = ET.parse(content)

        lst_jugador = tree.findall('data/test')

        for jugador in lst_jugador:

             print (jugador.find('name').text, jugador.get("id"))


myroot = tree.getroot()

# remove tag content
for x in filenames:
     myroot = tree.getroot()
for x in myroot[1][2]:
    x.text = None
for x in myroot[1][17]:
    x.text = None
    filenames.write('data/new.xml')
```

I get a **NameError: name 'tree' is not defined**.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong or how to do this in a different way?
I was able to do this with a single xml file, I am struggling with reading and writing multiple xml files.

This is how the code looked like for reading and writing a single file (which works):

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

mytree = ET.parse('data/test.xml')
myroot = mytree.getroot()

for x in myroot[1][2]:
    x.text = None
for x in myroot[1][17]:
    x.text = None
    mytree.write('data/new.xml')
```

This is a shortened version of my xml file:

```
    <xml_file>
    <tag>
        <tag_1>00000000</tag_1>
    </tag>
    <test>
        <one>
            <one_1>test</one_1>
            <one_2>test</one_2>
            <one_3>test</one_3>
            <one_4>test</one_4>
            <one_5>test</one_5>
            <one_6>test</one_6>
            <one_7>test</one_7>
            <one_8>test</one_8>
            <one_9>test</one_9>
            <one_10>test</one_10>
            <one_11>test</one_11>
            <one_12>test</one_12>
        </one>
        <two>
            <two_1>test</two_1>
            <two_2>test</two_2>
            <two_3>test</two_3>
            <two_4>test</two_4>
            <two_5>test</two_5>
            <two_6>test</two_6>
            <two_7>test</two_7>
            <two_8>test</two_8>
        </two>
    </test>
</xml_file>
```

Comment: Please post sample XML and desired result in body of question.

Answer (score 1):

Simply generalize your working process in a defined method then iteratively pass files into function using [**`map`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map).

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import glob

# DEFINED METHOD RECEIVING FILE AS PARAMETER
def update_xml(xml_file)
    mytree = ET.parse(xml_file)
    myroot = mytree.getroot()

    for x in myroot[1][2]:
        x.text = None
    for x in myroot[1][17]:
        x.text = None

    mytree.write(xml_file)      # WRITE NEW TREE TO DISK
    return mytree               # RETURN NEW TREE IN FUNCTION


# ITERATIVELY UPDATE XML WITH map()
filenames = glob.glob("[0-9][a-z](*).xml")

new_trees = list(map(update_xml, filenames))
```

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful! One more question: I need to identify the tags via name instead of position. So I tried using this:    `mytree.find('.//tagname_1').text = ''`
But I get this error: **AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'**.

Comment: Like you do now, first check node exists with `if` then assign `text`. Or iterate with `findall`.

Answer (score -1):

This is a formatting issue, you need to have 'tree = ET.parse(content)' on the same level as 'myroot = tree.getroot()'

try this

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import glob

#parse xml files
filenames = glob.glob("[0-9][a-z](*).xml")

for filename in filenames:

    with open(filename, 'r', encoding="utf-8") as content:

        tree = ET.parse(content)

        lst_jugador = tree.findall('data/test')

        for jugador in lst_jugador:

             print (jugador.find('name').text, jugador.get("id"))

tree = ET.parse(content)
myroot = tree.getroot()

# remove tag content
for x in filenames:
     myroot = tree.getroot()
for x in myroot[1][2]:
    x.text = None
for x in myroot[1][17]:
    x.text = None
    filenames.write('data/new.xml')
```

Comment: This didn´t work, I just got: "NameError: name 'content' is not defined".